# Is there a function to convert a string like YYYY-QQ to date in AWS Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement for Redshift SQL where I need to convert a column like '2020-Q2' to start of the quarter date 2020-04-01. I tried few other posts but they don't seem to work.  Read somewhere I can use below query but it doesn't really work:

```
select to_timestamp(to_date('2015-Q1', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

I am planning to make a UDF but if there is an in-built function already, please share.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following works in Postgres and I think it should work in Redshift:

```
select to_date(left(yyyyqq, 4), 'YYYY') + (right(yyyyqq, 1)::int - 1) * interval '3 month'
from (select '2015-Q3' as yyyyqq) x
```

Comment: Gordon to the rescue, yet again!!